# Magento 2: product image upload error

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have run below code

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image;
include("app/bootstrap.php");
    //$product_id = 4814;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $simple_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');


    $storeId = '1'; //Store ID
    $product_id = 4814; 
    $productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
    $product = $productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product_id);

    echo $imagePath = '/var/import/bulb.jpg'; // path of the image
    //exit();
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);

    $product->save();
```

And getting following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException:
>   The image doesn't exist. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor.php:145
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product.php(1577):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor->addImage(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor),
>   '/var/import/bul...', Array, false, false) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\generated\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor.php(895):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->addImageToMediaGallery('/var/import/bul...',
>   Array, false, false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\image.php(22):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->addImageToMediaGallery('/var/import/bul...',
>   Array, false, false) #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento23\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor.php
>   on line 145

Answer (score 1):

Replace path

```
$imagePath = '/var/import/bulb.jpg';
```

**to**

```
$imagePath = $this->getBaseUrl() . 'var/import/bulb.jpg';
```

Comment: I have been added with hard code url but same error occurring.

Comment: @Anwar is your path correct ?

Comment: Yes image path is correct.

Comment: @Anwar Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259303/add-remove-image-programmatically-to-product-magento2

Answer (score 0):

Please, Try this method

```
<?php
/**
 * file location:
 * app/code/VendorName/ExtensionName/Service/ImportImageService.php
 */

namespace VendorName\ExtensionName\Service;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;

/**
 * Class ImportImageService
 * assign images to products by image URL
 */
class ImportImageService
{
    /**
     * Directory List
     *
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * File interface
     *
     * @var File
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * ImportImageService constructor
     *
     * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
     * @param File $file
     */
    public function __construct(
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        File $file
    ) {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Main service executor
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param string $imageUrl
     * @param array $imageType
     * @param bool $visible
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function execute($product, $imageUrl, $visible = false, $imageType = [])
    {
        /** @var string $tmpDir */
        $tmpDir = $this->getMediaDirTmpDir();
        /** create folder if it is not exists */
        $this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
        /** @var string $newFileName */
        $newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($imageUrl);
        /** read file from URL and copy it to the new destination */
        $result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
        if ($result) {
            /** add saved file to the $product gallery */
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($newFileName, $imageType, true, $visible);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Media directory name for the temporary file storage
     * pub/media/tmp
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getMediaDirTmpDir()
    {

        return $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp';
    }
}
```